# How to use named parameters with unnamed parameters in PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have this script `init.ps1`

```
param($s)
write-host $s
write-host $args

...
```

The idea is that, when I invoke `init.ps1 service up`, `$s` would be empty, and `$args` would be `service up`.

But when I do that, I got `$s` as `service`, `$args` as `$up`.

I intend `$s` to be used like `init.ps1 service up -s auth` to start the auth service only, for example.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

Some things to keep in mind:

- `$args` will contains all the arguments passed down to your scripts.
- If using named parameter (eg: `$s` in your case), then `$args` will contains any remaining parameters not bound to anything else.
- Parameters delimiter is the space.

Based on that, what you have as result is what is expected.
In `init.ps1 service up`, you have the script, then 2 parameters (space is the delimiter here, remember). **Service** get passed down as a positional parameter to the first one available `$s`. You did not define a second parameter in your script so the remaining argument **up** get passed down to the default handler `$args`, which contains the remaining parameter.

What you want is something more like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $s,
    $state
)

# Do what you need
Write-Host $s -ForegroundColor Cyan 
Write-Host $state -ForegroundColor Green
```

From there, you'd invoke it like that:

`& "C:\Path\to\YourScript.ps1" -s auth -state "Service Up"` 
or, positionally
`& "C:\Path\to\YourScript.ps1" auth "Service Up"`

Note: You don't have to specify the `[CmdletBinding()]` part but it will allow you to pass down common parameters such as `-Verbose`, `-ErrorAction`, etc...

**About `$Args`**

> Contains an array of values for undeclared parameters that are passed
> to a function, script, or script block. When you create a function,
> you can declare the parameters by using the param keyword or by adding
> a comma-separated list of parameters in parentheses after the function
> name.
>
> In an event action, the $args variable contains objects that represent
> the event arguments of the event that is being processed. This
> variable is populated only within the Action block of an event
> registration command. The value of this variable can also be found in
> the SourceArgs property of the PSEventArgs object that Get-Event
> returns.

Note: `$Args` is an automatic variable. There's a couple of them in Powershell that you should be aware of. They can prove useful and knowing of them will prevent you from trying to use them for other purposes (this would have unintended effects)

Reference: [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Very nice, wasnt aware of that behavior from `$args`

Comment: in Windows Powershell this is not true for `function <<..>> process {` , you need to use `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]` . with using `args` as the name, will work .